# Common main title of a figure panel compiled with par(mfrow)

Tags: r, graph, plot, title, par

I have a  compilation of  4 plots drawn together with `par(mfrow=c(2,2))`. I would like to draw a common title for the 2 above plots and a  common title for the 2 below panels that are centered between the 2 left and right plots.

Is this possible?

Comment: Doing that would sort of obscure the "title", wouldn't it? Why do you not want it at the top of all the plots?

Comment: What i meant is one title for the 2 upper plots and one title for the 2 lower plots. I corrected my Q

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This *should* work, but you'll need to play around with the `line` argument to get it just right:

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
plot(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Petal.Width)
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Width)
plot(iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Petal.Width)
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Width)
mtext("My 'Title' in a strange place", side = 3, line = -21, outer = TRUE)
```

[image]

`mtext` stands for "margin text". `side = 3` says to place it in the "top" margin. `line = -21` says to offset the placement by 21 lines. `outer = TRUE` says it's OK to use the outer-margin area.

To add another "title" at the top, you can add it using, say, `mtext("My 'Title' in a strange place", side = 3, line = -2, outer = TRUE)`

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you. I didn't know that `mtext` can use negative values.

Comment: @ECII, No problem. In general, though, I would think that you would approach this using `layout`, as demonstrated in @Didzis's answer.

Answer (score 47):

You can use the function `layout()` and set two plotting regions which occurs in both columns (see the repeating numbers 1 and 3 in the `matrix()`). Then I used `plot.new()` and `text()` to set titles. You can play with margins and heights to get better representation.

```
x<-1:10
par(mar=c(2.5,2.5,1,1))
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,1,5,3,6),ncol=2),heights=c(1,3,1,3))
plot.new()
text(0.5,0.5,"First title",cex=2,font=2)
plot(x)
plot.new()
text(0.5,0.5,"Second title",cex=2,font=2)
hist(x)
boxplot(x)
barplot(x)
```

[image]

Comment: You get my vote here. I think `layout` is definitely the way to go, but wanted to show the `mtext` option too.

Answer (score 24):

The same but in bold can be done using `title(...)` with the same arguments as above:

```
title("My 'Title' in a strange place", line = -21, outer = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's another way to do it, using the `line2user` function from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29893376/489704).

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
plot(runif(100))
plot(runif(100))
text(line2user(line=mean(par('mar')[c(2, 4)]), side=2), 
     line2user(line=2, side=3), 'First title', xpd=NA, cex=2, font=2)

plot(runif(100))
plot(runif(100))
text(line2user(line=mean(par('mar')[c(2, 4)]), side=2), 
     line2user(line=2, side=3), 'Second title', xpd=NA, cex=2, font=2)
```

[image: centered_titles]

Here, the title is positioned 2 lines higher than the upper edge of the plot, as indicated by `line2user(2, 3)`. We centre it by offsetting it with respect to the 2nd and 4th plots, by half of the combined width of the left and right margins, i.e. `mean(par('mar')[c(2, 4)])`.

---

`line2user` expresses an offset (number of lines) from an axis in user coordinates, and is defined as:

```
line2user <- function(line, side) {
  lh <- par('cin')[2] * par('cex') * par('lheight')
  x_off <- diff(grconvertX(0:1, 'inches', 'user'))
  y_off <- diff(grconvertY(0:1, 'inches', 'user'))
  switch(side,
         `1` = par('usr')[3] - line * y_off * lh,
         `2` = par('usr')[1] - line * x_off * lh,
         `3` = par('usr')[4] + line * y_off * lh,
         `4` = par('usr')[2] + line * x_off * lh,
         stop("side must be 1, 2, 3, or 4", call.=FALSE))
}
```

Comment: Nice one @jbaums

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DidzisElferts answer, I just found a great documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/layout)

Just try the following code. I helped me a lot to understand what's going on:

```
def.par <- par(no.readonly = TRUE) # save default, for resetting...

## divide the device into two rows and two columns
## allocate figure 1 all of row 1
## allocate figure 2 the intersection of column 2 and row 2
layout(matrix(c(1,1,0,2), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE))
## show the regions that have been allocated to each plot
layout.show(2)

## divide device into two rows and two columns
## allocate figure 1 and figure 2 as above
## respect relations between widths and heights
nf <- layout(matrix(c(1,1,0,2), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE), respect = TRUE)
layout.show(nf)

## create single figure which is 5cm square
nf <- layout(matrix(1), widths = lcm(5), heights = lcm(5))
layout.show(nf)


##-- Create a scatterplot with marginal histograms -----

x <- pmin(3, pmax(-3, stats::rnorm(50)))
y <- pmin(3, pmax(-3, stats::rnorm(50)))
xhist <- hist(x, breaks = seq(-3,3,0.5), plot = FALSE)
yhist <- hist(y, breaks = seq(-3,3,0.5), plot = FALSE)
top <- max(c(xhist$counts, yhist$counts))
xrange <- c(-3, 3)
yrange <- c(-3, 3)
nf <- layout(matrix(c(2,0,1,3),2,2,byrow = TRUE), c(3,1), c(1,3), TRUE)
layout.show(nf)

par(mar = c(3,3,1,1))
plot(x, y, xlim = xrange, ylim = yrange, xlab = "", ylab = "")
par(mar = c(0,3,1,1))
barplot(xhist$counts, axes = FALSE, ylim = c(0, top), space = 0)
par(mar = c(3,0,1,1))
barplot(yhist$counts, axes = FALSE, xlim = c(0, top), space = 0, horiz = TRUE)

par(def.par)  #- reset to default
```