# Get margin line locations in log space

Tags: r, plot

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125019/get-margin-line-locations-mgp-in-user-coordinates) I asked how to get margin line locations in user coordinates. I received an excellent answer in the form of the `line2user` function. However, I cannot figure out how to modify the function to work when either the x or y axis is on a log scale.

I have made a couple modifications to accommodate a log-scaled axis:

```
line2user <- function(line, side, log = "") {
  lh <- par('cin')[2] * par('cex') * par('lheight')
  x_off <- diff(grconvertX(0:1, 'inches', 'user'))
  y_off <- diff(grconvertY(0:1, 'inches', 'user'))
  usr <- par('usr') ## Added by me
  if (grepl("x", log)) usr[1:2] <- 10^usr[1:2] ## Added by me
  if (grepl("y", log)) usr[3:4] <- 10^usr[3:4] ## Added by me
  switch(side,
         `1` = usr[3] - line * y_off * lh,
         `2` = usr[1] - line * x_off * lh,
         `3` = usr[4] + line * y_off * lh,
         `4` = usr[2] + line * x_off * lh,
         stop("Side must be 1, 2, 3, or 4", call.=FALSE))
}
```

However, I cannot figure out how to properly adjust the `xoff` and `yoff` variables to draw the proper lines. Illustration:

```
setup_plot <- function(log = "") {
  par(mar = c(2, 10, 2, 2), oma = rep(2, 4))
  plot.new()
  plot.window(xlim = c(1, 10), ylim = c(1, 10), log = log)
  box(which = "plot", lwd = 2, col = "gray40")
  box(which = "figure", lwd = 2, col = "darkred")
  box(which = "outer", lwd = 2, col = "darkgreen")
  text(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, 
       labels = "Plot Region", 
       col = "gray40", font = 2)
  mtext(side = 3, text = "Figure region", line = 0.5, col = "darkred", font = 2)
  mtext(side = 3, text = "Device region", line = 2.5, col = "darkgreen", font = 2)
  for (i in 0:9) {
    mtext(side = 2, col = "darkred", text = paste0("Line", i), line = i)
  }
}

setup_plot(log = "x")
abline(v=line2user(line=0:9, side=2, log = "x"), xpd=TRUE, lty=2)
```

[image]

The compressed lines make sense after considering the following example:

```
plot(10)
diff(grconvertX(0:1, 'inches', 'user'))
## [1] 0.08121573 (on my device)

plot(10, log = "x")
diff(grconvertX(0:1, 'inches', 'user'))
## [1] 0.0297354 (on my device)
```

How can I get the correct `x_off` and `y_off` values when working with a log-scaled axis?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a version that works with log-scale *and* linear scale axes. The trick is to express line locations in `npc` coordinates rather than `user` coordinates, since the latter are of course not linear when axes are on log scales.

```
line2user <- function(line, side) {
  lh <- par('cin')[2] * par('cex') * par('lheight')
  x_off <- diff(grconvertX(c(0, lh), 'inches', 'npc'))
  y_off <- diff(grconvertY(c(0, lh), 'inches', 'npc'))
  switch(side,
         `1` = grconvertY(-line * y_off, 'npc', 'user'),
         `2` = grconvertX(-line * x_off, 'npc', 'user'),
         `3` = grconvertY(1 + line * y_off, 'npc', 'user'),
         `4` = grconvertX(1 + line * x_off, 'npc', 'user'),
         stop("Side must be 1, 2, 3, or 4", call.=FALSE))
}
```

And here are a couple of examples, applied to your `setup_plot` with `mar=c(5, 5, 5, 5)`:

```
setup_plot()
axis(1, line=5)
axis(2, line=5)
abline(h=line2user(0:4, 1), lty=3, xpd=TRUE)
abline(v=line2user(0:4, 2), lty=3, xpd=TRUE)
abline(h=line2user(0:4, 3), lty=3, xpd=TRUE)
abline(v=line2user(0:4, 4), lty=3, xpd=TRUE)
```

[image]

```
setup_plot(log='x')
axis(1, line=5)
axis(2, line=5)
abline(h=line2user(0:4, 1), lty=3, xpd=TRUE)
abline(v=line2user(0:4, 2), lty=3, xpd=TRUE)
abline(h=line2user(0:4, 3), lty=3, xpd=TRUE)
abline(v=line2user(0:4, 4), lty=3, xpd=TRUE)
```

[image]

```
setup_plot(log='y')
axis(1, line=5)
axis(2, line=5)
abline(h=line2user(0:4, 1), lty=3, xpd=TRUE)
abline(v=line2user(0:4, 2), lty=3, xpd=TRUE)
abline(h=line2user(0:4, 3), lty=3, xpd=TRUE)
abline(v=line2user(0:4, 4), lty=3, xpd=TRUE)
```

[image]

```
setup_plot(log='xy')
axis(1, line=5)
axis(2, line=5)
abline(h=line2user(0:4, 1), lty=3, xpd=TRUE)
abline(v=line2user(0:4, 2), lty=3, xpd=TRUE)
abline(h=line2user(0:4, 3), lty=3, xpd=TRUE)
abline(v=line2user(0:4, 4), lty=3, xpd=TRUE)
```

[image]