# R: Suppress ticks and labels at endpoints of axis

Tags: r, plot

I have code producing the below pasted plot

```
x <- c(2, 3, 4)
y <- c(2.5, 4.1, 5.5)

plot(x, y, type = "o", xlim = c(1, 5), ylim = c(2, 6), axes = FALSE, bty = "n")
axis(side = 1, at = seq(1, 5, 1))
axis(side = 2, at = seq(2, 6, 1), las = 2)
```

[image: The plot currently looks like this]

I would like to have **neither ticks nor labels** at position 1 and 5, but the **axis should still be drawn**. This is what I am looking for:
[image: The plot should look like this]

When using `labels = c("", 2, 3, 4, "")` ticks are drawn.  When using `tick = FALSE`, I get no axis. Does anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to draw the line manually. Using the `line2user` function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30835971/1623354):

```
x <- c(2, 3, 4)
y <- c(2.5, 4.1, 5.5)

plot(x, y, type = "o", xlim = c(1, 5), ylim = c(2, 6), axes = FALSE, bty = "n")
axis(side = 1, at = 2:4)

lines(x = c(1, 5), y = rep(line2user(0, side = 1), 2), xpd = TRUE)
axis(side = 2, at = seq(2, 6, 1), las = 2)
```

[image]

Note, the `line2user` function just gives the position of the lines in the user coordinate system. You need the `xpd = TRUE` to draw outside the plotting region.

Comment: Worked for me, after changing your code to
`lines(x = c(1, 2), y = rep(line2user(0, side = 1), 2), xpd = TRUE)` and 
`lines(x = c(4, 5), y = rep(line2user(0, side = 1), 2), xpd = TRUE)`. Otherwise the axes got plotted twice (looked ugly on my screen:).

Comment: @pipomas That is really unnecessary -- you can just as easily draw one line that goes from 1 to 5. They should overlap exactly. But, I'm glad it worked for you.

Comment: You are right. The axis is looking fine when exporting the plot as image or pdf.