# ggplot2: reorder bars from highest to lowest in each facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

In the `df` below, I want to reorder bars from highest to lowest ***in each facet***

I tried

```
df <- df %>% tidyr::gather("var", "value", 2:4)
ggplot(df, aes (x = reorder(id, -value), y = value, fill = id))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+facet_wrap(~var, ncol =3)
```

It gave me 
[image]

It didn't order the bars from highest to lowest in each facet.

I figured out another way to get what I want. I had to plot each variable at a time, then combine all plots using `grid.arrange()`

```
#I got this function from @eipi10's answer
#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38637261/perfectly-align-several-plots/38640937#38640937  
#Function to extract legend
# https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Share-a-legend-between-two-ggplot2-graphs
g_legend<-function(a.gplot) {
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
  return(legend)
}

p1 <- ggplot(df[df$var== "A", ], aes (x = reorder(id, -value), y = value, fill = id))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_wrap(~var, ncol =3)

fin_legend <- g_legend(p1)
p1 <- p1 + guides(fill= F)

p2 <- ggplot(df[df$var== "B", ], aes (x = reorder(id, -value), y = value, fill = id))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_wrap(~var, ncol =3)+guides(fill=FALSE) 

p3 <- ggplot(df[df$var== "C", ], aes (x = reorder(id, -value), y = value, fill = id))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_wrap(~var, ncol =3)+guides(fill=FALSE) 


grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, fin_legend, ncol =4, widths = c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 0.5))
```

The result is what I want
[image]

I wonder if there is a straightforward way that can help me order the bars from highest to lowest in all facets without having to plot each variable separtely and then combine them. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

**DATA**

```
df <-  read.table(text = c("
id  A   B   C
site1   10  15  20
site2   20  10  30
site3   30  20  25
site4   40  35  40
site5   50  30  35"), header = T)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The approach below uses a specially prepared variable for the x-axis with `facet_wrap()` but uses the `labels` parameter to `scale_x_discrete()` to display the correct x-axis labels:

## Prepare data

I'm more fluent in `data.table`, so this is used here. Feel free to use what ever package you prefer for data manipulation.

**Edit**: Removed second dummy variable, only `ord` is required

```
library(data.table)   
# reshape from wide to long
molten <- melt(setDT(df), id.vars = "id")
# create dummy var which reflects order when sorted alphabetically
molten[, ord := sprintf("%02i", frank(molten, variable, -value, ties.method = "first"))]

molten
#       id variable value ord
# 1: site1        A    10  05
# 2: site2        A    20  04
# 3: site3        A    30  03
# 4: site4        A    40  02
# 5: site5        A    50  01
# 6: site1        B    15  09
# 7: site2        B    10  10
# 8: site3        B    20  08
# 9: site4        B    35  06
#10: site5        B    30  07
#11: site1        C    20  15
#12: site2        C    30  13
#13: site3        C    25  14
#14: site4        C    40  11
#15: site5        C    35  12
```

## Create plot

```
library(ggplot2)
# `ord` is plotted on x-axis instead of `id`
ggplot(molten, aes(x = ord, y = value, fill = id)) +
  # geom_col() is replacement for geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  geom_col() +
  # independent x-axis scale in each facet, 
  # drop absent factor levels (not the case here)
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free_x", drop = TRUE) +
  # use named character vector to replace x-axis labels
  scale_x_discrete(labels = molten[, setNames(as.character(id), ord)]) + 
  # replace x-axis title
  xlab("id")
```

[image]

## Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "
id  A   B   C
site1   10  15  20
site2   20  10  30
site3   30  20  25
site4   40  35  40
site5   50  30  35", header = T)
```

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed explanation for each line of the code. Many thanks Uwe.

Comment: Excellent solution!!! Wish this logic was built into ggplot facet functions

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to lose the X axis labels, you can do this by using the actual y values as the x aesthetic, then dropping unused factor levels in each facet:

```
ggplot(df, aes (x = factor(-value), y = value, fill = id))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity", na.rm = TRUE)+
    facet_wrap(~var, ncol =3, scales = "free_x", drop = TRUE) +
    theme(
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()
    )
```

Result:

[image]

The loss of x-axis labels is probably not too bad here as you still have the colours to go on (and the x-axis is confusing anyway since it's not consistent across facets).

Comment: This is a pure genius! Thank you a lot!