# Reorder factor not working on grouped data

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have this dataframe that I call `top_mesh_terms`

```
structure(list(topic = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), term = c("Diabetes Mellitus", 
"Depression", "Syndrome", "Diabetes Mellitus, Type 2", "Lung Diseases", 
"Colorectal Neoplasms", "Osteoarthritis", "Sclerosis", "Lymphoma", 
"Lung Diseases, Obstructive", "Diabetes Mellitus", "Disease", 
"Hypertension", "Syndrome", "Carcinoma", "Infection", "Coronary Disease", 
"Lung Neoplasms", "Obesity", "Infarction"), beta = c(0.0196989252285569, 
0.018472562347772, 0.0175512616261399, 0.0146680780420432, 0.0133507951269683, 
0.01224603797061, 0.0116799262133244, 0.0107893497000735, 0.00926496950657875, 
0.00891926541108836, 0.0324598963852768, 0.0198135918084849, 
0.0162689075944415, 0.0157166860189554, 0.014855885836076, 0.0127365678034364, 
0.0109544570325732, 0.00964124158432716, 0.00956596829604797, 
0.00880281359338067)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

As the title suggests, I'd like to reorder the `term` column by `beta` and then draw a bar chart. I hoped to see a bar chart with ordered bars, but that is not the case. Here is the code I used and the resulting graph:

```
top_mesh_terms %>% 
  group_by(topic) %>% 
  mutate(term = fct_reorder(term, beta)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(term, beta)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ topic, scales = "free") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  labs(x = "MeSH Term",
       y = "Beta")
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624394/ggplot-bar-plot-with-facet-dependent-order-of-categories or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176546/ggplot2-reorder-bars-from-highest-to-lowest-in-each-facet ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the `group_by`. The levels of a factor have a single order, it can't differ by group.  If we get rid of your `group_by` and `ungroup` commands, everything works:

```
    top_mesh_terms %>% 
      mutate(term = reorder(term, beta)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(term, beta)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
      facet_wrap(~ topic, scales = "free") +
      coord_flip() +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
      labs(x = "MeSH Term",
           y = "Beta")
```

[image]

(Btw, `forcats` has some really nice functions, but if the only one you need is `fct_reorder` you might as well use `base::reorder` - it does the same thing without the extra package dependency.)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
top_mesh_terms %>% 
  group_by(topic) %>% 
  mutate(term = fct_reorder(term, beta)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reorder(term, beta), beta)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ topic, scales = "free") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  labs(x = "MeSH Term",
       y = "Beta")
```

I used the `ggplot(aes(reorder(term, beta)` to change the order.

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly added a footnote to your answer when I meant to add it to mine. Just rolled back the change.