# Arranging many graphs in a same plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, facet-wrap, ggpubr

I would like to have different graphics in just one plot, however the command I used for it (`grid.arrange`) is distorting the bars of my chart. In addition to this I would like to place each chart's title (A, B, C ..) at the top of the chart and not on the side as it appears.

In figure 1, I have a single graph (correct bars) and in the second all graphs together. Could someone help me readjust this command?

Thanks

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

A<-ggplot(dados, aes(specie, A)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.5, aes(colour = trophic, fill = trophic,
                            group = trophic)) +
  rotate_x_text(angle = 55)

B<-ggplot(dados, aes(specie, B)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.5, aes(colour = trophic, fill = trophic,
                            group = trophic)) +
  rotate_x_text(angle = 55)

C<-ggplot(dados, aes(specie, C)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.5, aes(colour = trophic, fill = trophic,
                            group = trophic)) +
  rotate_x_text(angle = 55)

D<-ggplot(dados, aes(specie, D)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.5, aes(colour = trophic, fill = trophic,
                            group = trophic)) +
  rotate_x_text(angle = 55)

E<-ggplot(dados, aes(specie, E)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.5, aes(colour = trophic, fill = trophic,
                            group = trophic)) +
  rotate_x_text(angle = 55)

G<-ggplot(dados, aes(specie, G)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.5, aes(colour = trophic, fill = trophic,
                            group = trophic)) +
  rotate_x_text(angle = 55)

H<-ggplot(dados, aes(specie, H)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.5, aes(colour = trophic, fill = trophic,
                            group = trophic)) +
  rotate_x_text(angle = 55)

I<-ggplot(dados, aes(specie, I)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.5, aes(colour = trophic, fill = trophic,
                            group = trophic)) +
  rotate_x_text(angle = 55)

J<-ggplot(dados, aes(specie, J)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.5, aes(colour = trophic, fill = trophic,
                            group = trophic)) +
  rotate_x_text(angle = 55)

grid.arrange(A, B, C, D, E, G, H, I, J, ncol=3)
```

My data:

```
specie  A   B   C   D   E   G   H   I   J   bodymass    trophic
AAThry_swin 72  0   76.8    63.2    0   0   0   1.6 0   4000    1
ABHys_afri  23.2    0   77.6    68.8    0   0   0   0   0   14936.02    1
ACSylv_grim 48  0   52  0   0.8 0   0   15.2    0   15639.15    1
ADTrag_scri 100 2.4 100 2.4 17.6    0   3.2 14.4    0   43250.39    1
AERed_aru   100 0.8 53.6    0   2.4 0   25.6    0   0   58059.24    1
AFHipp_eq   14.4    0   6.4 0   4.8 0   4   0   0   264173.96   1
AGTrag_oryx 16  0   15.2    0   4   0   0   0   0   562592.69   1
AHSync_caf  81.6    0   41.6    8.8 8.8 0   25.6    2.4 0   592665.98   1
AILox_afric 1.6 28  1.6 0.8 3.2 0   47.2    3.2 0   3824539.93  1
BAOtol_cras 7.2 0   1.6 22.4    0   0   0   0   0   1206.61 2
BBMiop_tal  1.6 0   1.6 54.4    0   0   0   0.8 0   1248.86 2
BCLep_cap   14.4    0   12  0   0   0   0   0   0   1500    2
BEGenet_gen 0   0   0   80.8    0   0   0   0   0   1756.17 2
BFPhil_mont 20.8    0   100 16.8    4.8 0   2.4 12.8    0   4896.05 2
BGChlor_cyn 72.8    0   16.8    100 0   0   0   1.6 0   5000.01 2
BHCerc_mit  5.6 0   11.2    100 0   0   0   0.8 0   5041.29 2
BICivet_civ 43.2    0   52.8    19.2    0   0   0   16.8    41.6    12075.58    2
BJPota_larv 100 0   84  64  14.4    0   1.6 18.4    1.6 69063.79    2
BLHipp_amph 22.4    0   0   8.8 0   0   0   4   0   1536310.4   2
CALept_serv 0.8 56  3.2 80  0   14.4    0   23.2    78.4    11999.96    3
CBLyc_pict  0.8 10.4    0   23.2    0   12  0.8 9.6 19.2    21999.99    3
CCCan_mes   1.6 0   0   20.8    0   6.4 0   32  0   22000   3
CDPant_pa   18.4    24  1.6 12  0   17.6    27.2    4   8   52399.99    3
CEOryct_afer    11.2    1.6 22.4    0   0   0   0   5.6 4.8 56175.2 3
CFCroc_croc 51.2    0   0   22.4    0   5.6 0   1.6 0   63369.98    3
CGPant_le   0   15.2    0.8 27.2    0   57.6    24  1.6 1.6 158623.93   3
```

[image]

[image: Fig 2- all graphics together]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
library(dplyr)

dados %>%
  gather(type, value, -c("specie", "bodymass", "trophic")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=specie, y=value)) + geom_col(alpha=0.5, aes(color=trophic, fill=trophic, group=trophic)) +
  facet_wrap(~type, ncol=3) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=55))
```

[image: plot]

Edit:

To control the color of trophic, you need to change it from a continuous variable to a factor:

```
dados %>%
  gather(type, value, -c("specie", "bodymass", "trophic")) %>%
  mutate(trophic = as.factor(trophic)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=specie, y=value)) + geom_col(alpha=0.5, aes(color=trophic, fill=trophic, group=trophic)) +
  facet_wrap(~type, ncol=3) +
  scale_fill_manual("trophic", values = c("#66FF33", "#FFFF00", "#FFCC99")) +
  scale_color_manual("trophic", values = c("#66FF33", "#FFFF00", "#FFCC99")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=55))
```

[image: edit]

Comment: Thanks Alan
This is exactly what I wanted. Please one last question, I am trying to put specific colors in the columns of each trophic level, but I am getting error messages with the scale_color_manual and scale_fill_manual command I'm using. Do you know how could I fix it? Thank you

I'm trying with:

  ggplot(aes(x=specie, y=value)) + geom_col(alpha=0.5, aes(color=trophic, fill=trophic, group=trophic)) +
  scale_color_manual("trophic", values = c("66FF33", "FFFF00", "FFCC99")) +
  scale_fill_manual("trophic", values = c("66FF33", "FFFF00", "FFCC99"))

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `graphics` (meant only as an outline for using `layout` and the custom functions):

```
addfiglab <- function(lab, xl = par()$mar[2], yl = par()$mar[3], cex = 1) {

  text(x = line2user(xl, 2), y = line2user(yl, 3), 
       lab, xpd = NA, font = 2, cex = cex, adj = c(0, 1))

}

line2user <- function(line, side, outer = FALSE) {
  unit <- if (outer) "nic" else "npc"
  lh <- par('cin')[2] * par('cex') * par('lheight')
  x_off <- diff(grconvertX(c(0, lh), 'inches', unit))
  y_off <- diff(grconvertY(c(0, lh), 'inches', unit))
  switch(side,
         `1` = grconvertY(-line * y_off, unit, 'user'),
         `2` = grconvertX(-line * x_off, unit, 'user'),
         `3` = grconvertY(1 + line * y_off, unit, 'user'),
         `4` = grconvertX(1 + line * x_off, unit, 'user'),
         stop("Side must be 1, 2, 3, or 4", call.=FALSE))
}

layout(matrix(c(rep(1, 9), 2:10), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE))
plot(1:10); addfiglab("A")
for (i in 2:10) {plot(i); addfiglab(LETTERS[i])}
```

[image]

**[Credit for the line2user function!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30835971/1623354)**