# how to add the sign of the graph in r

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want add the sign (a), (b), (c) to my figures. what I mean is add the (a),(b),(c) to the upper left of the graph

```
a<-rnorm(1000,10,1)
plot(a)

b<-rnorm(1000,10,10)
plot(b)

c<-rnorm(1000,1,1)
plot(c)
```

Could anyone tell me how can I add this?

Thank you

[image]

like this

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084140/include-figure-labels-in-r-markdown-for-side-by-side-plots or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38439211/figure-labels-add-text-on-graphs-in-the-same-location-despite-figure-size

Comment: sorry what I mean is add the (a) (b) at the upper left of the graph

Comment: please see my new edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use base R, you can try with `mtext`

```
a<-rnorm(1000,10,1)
plot(a)
mtext(side=3, line=0.5, '(a)', adj = 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in the package `patchwork` which allows for good alignment of multiple graphs and you can add the letters via the `geom_title()` argument. The website for descriptions can be found: https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/